# discord auto role when status matches

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Ive tries some different things to make this work but it's not wanting to work

so am basicly trying to check someones custom status for a specific thing if there is for example .gg/test in it and give them a role than

My code

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get("927284722059595828");
  const member = newPresence.member
  const activities = member.user.presence.activities[0];

  if (activities && (activities.state.includes( ".gg/test" ) || activities.state.includes("discord.gg/test" ))) {
    return newPresence.member.roles.add(role)
  } else {
    if(member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
      newPresence.member.roles.remove(role)
    }
  }
})
```

so can anyone correct the code to the correct format

and if possable make this multi server usable with a command thanks

the error i get

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at Client.<anonymous> (/root/raegay2/boy.js:19:36)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at PresenceUpdateAction.handle (/root/raegay2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/PresenceUpdate.js:39:19)
    at Object.module.exports [as PRESENCE_UPDATE] (/root/raegay2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/PRESENCE_UPDATE.js:4:33)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/root/raegay2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/root/raegay2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/root/raegay2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/root/raegay2/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/root/raegay2/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:825:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and it worked fine. Did you enable **Presence Intent** on your bots discord developer page? If you are using Gateway Intents, you must specify the `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent in order to receive Presence Update events.

Comment: please check my most again ive updated it with the error

yes the setting is on